# Separate store year , month value in SQL db

Tags: sql, datetime

```
insert into Salary (Year, Month, Day, Amount, Deduction, Employee_ID)
values ('2012', '12', '4', '400', '50', '6')
```

it gives me error

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Comment: post the table structure..

Comment: Just read the error... U are trying to insert varchar in format that is not compatible with the table structure

Comment: Without even knowing the structure, my guess is that you're trying to pass 12 and 4 into date or datetime fields and that just isn't allowed as it's trying to turn these into valid dates and 12 and 4 are not enough information to do that.

Comment: You should use a proper `date` data type. Buf if you insist on storing them in separate columns, then at least use numbers, not strings. `'2012'` is a character literal. `2012` is a number in SQL

Answer (score 0):

It is better to store the date in a single column by specifying the datatype date to the column. Saving like this is not efficient.

Use the datatype `DATE`.

```
Column name            datatype
------------           -------    
EmployeeId             Int
Salary_Date            Date 
Amount                 Double
```

Please let me know if this is not what you're looking for. Hope this helps :)

Comment: Please **do not** use `double` for money values! `double` is prone to rounding errors - not recommend - use `decimal(p,s)` instead and use appropriate values for `p` (precision - number of total digits) and `s` (scale - number of digits after the decimal point)

Comment: Thanks a lot! @marc_s Didn't know that. I'll be following your suggestion from now .

Answer (score 0):

You question has been answered in the comments to your request. Make sure to use proper data types and see to it that types match when you access the columns.

However, I'd like to say a word to Year, Month, and Day integers versus one date column:

Usually you would store dates in a date column of course. This is what the data type `date` is made for. But there are reasons why not do so and rather store dates in separate integer columns.

In your example Month and Day could be nullable. Then you could enter different types of salaries: A salary for a month (year + month given), a special salary for the year (only year given), a salary granted on a certain day, say for a successfully finished project.

In a nutshell: If a part of the date can be null, then use separate integer columns. If not, use a date column.